# How do I get name and values from a dataset (key value pairs)?

Tags: powershell, datatable, dataset

I'm working with a system.data.dataset.

I want to loop through each row and create a psobject out of each one. The properties will be the column names. how is this possible? I want to dynamically create properties from the column names.

Comment: BTW, PowerShell adapt `DataRow` objects and expose columns as properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have [`DataRow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.datarow.aspx) object in `$DataRow` variable, you can do the following:

```
$DataRow.Table.Columns | ForEach-Object {$Properties=[ordered]@{}} `
                                        {$Properties.Add($_.ColumnName, $DataRow[$_])} `
                                        {[PSCustomObject]$Properties}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me in the *very specific* case of selecting from a single view.  
`$DataRow = Invoke-SqlCmd @OtherParams -query "select col1 from [A_View]"`
`$null -eq $DataRow.Table #True`

Answer (score 1):

I found it easy enough to do $datarow.psobject.properties and check each property against an array of properties like "rowerror" "rowstate" to filter that junk out and at that point I can to .name .value.

Comment: `$datarow.PSAdapted.PSObject.Properties` and no need to filter on "rowerror", "rowstate", etc.

Comment: Great! You should add that as an answer and I will mark it correct.